# on marker click in Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to get the marker that is clicked but i'm only getting the last marker name
I wish to apply dialog box on the selected marker but it's getting the last marker only

```
for(int i=0;i<objectResults.length();i++){
   JSONObject place=objectResults.getJSONObject(i);
   String store_id=place.getString("id");
   final String place_name=place.getString("name");
   double latitude1, longitude1;
   latitude1=place.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat");
   longitude1=place.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng");    

   MarkerOptions markerOptions=new MarkerOptions();
   LatLng latLng=new LatLng(latitude1,longitude1);
   markerOptions.position(latLng);
   markerOptions.title(place_name);
   mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

   mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
           Toast.makeText(getContext(),"YOU CLICKED ON "+place_name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           return false;
           }
       );
  }
```

thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get the title of the clicked marker using `getTitle()` where is storage `place_name`. like this:

```
   mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
           Toast.makeText(getContext(),"YOU CLICKED ON "+marker.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           return false;
           }
       );
  }
```